# Laravel 4/5 search form like

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a search form and functions, all done. Just to ask, is it possible to do it in Eloquent a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%'
```

To display some possible matching names. My current controller function:

```
    public function search()
{
    $name = Input::get('character');
    $searchResult = Player::where('name', '=', $name)->paginate(1);
    return View::make('search.search')
            ->with('name', $name)
            ->with('searchResult', $searchResult);
}
```

And my view:

```
    <form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" action="{{ URL::action('CharactersController@search') }}" method="get">
    <div class="input-append spancustom">
        <input type="text" class="search-query" name="character" placeholder="Character/guild name">
        <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Hmmm, yes, just set `like` as your comparison operator, and send the string with `%`'s. Something like this:

```
Player::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, never really made things with LIKE queries. How could I get the matching results? I already have a search form setup, but don't know how to view the matching results? Could you help me a bit? http://paste.laravel.com/K9O

Comment: You can take a look at how to display paginated results on [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage). Also, I'd recommend you indent your view code, it's barely readable.

Comment: This is helping me with my jquery autocomplete case, too.

Comment: This may produce unexpected results when user has inputted "%" into $name FYI.

Answer (score 21):

If you need to frequently use LIKE, you can simplify the problem a bit. A custom method like () can be created in  the model that inherits the Eloquent:

```
public  function scopeLike($query, $field, $value){
        return $query->where($field, 'LIKE', "%$value%");
}
```

So then you can use this method in such way:

```
 User::like('name', 'Tomas')->get();
```

Comment: where would I put the function 'scopeLike'?  Which file?

Comment: @JoshPetitt, you need to put this method inside your model and framework will see it automatically. (here is docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes see local scopes)

Answer (score 1):

With quote of string:

```
$value = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote('%' . strtolower($value) . '%');
$query->whereRaw('LOWER(your_table.your_column) LIKE ' . $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_student($match){
    return Student::where('name', 'like', $match .'%');
}
```

Try the above